# Printing out rows that don't match from two data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, search

Okay so I'm trying to take two separate data frames and sort through them to find ones that are in the first one but not in the second. What I have now prints every single row. Here is my code.

```py
for index, row in cleaned.iterrows():
    for ind, rows in Update.iterrows():
        if row['Pcode'] != rows['Pcode']:
            print('------------')
            print(row['Name'])
```

The code I'm basing this off of goes through the same table to find if two columns that are supposed to match do or don't match.

```py
for index, row in cleaned.iterrows():
    if row['P Name'].strip().lower() != row['PName'].strip().lower():
        print('---------------------------')
        print(row['P Name'] + ' ---> ' + row['PName'])
```

Comment: you can use `isin()` to do this. For example, `df1[~df1['Pcode'].isin(df2['Pcode'])]` will show you all rows in `df1` where `df1['Pcode']` does not exist in `df2`.

Comment: does isin() need to be a boolean? because i'm gettin the error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'```

Comment: Can you paste what you tried ? I doubt you used dataframes.